# Alerting system that receives and sends alert to multiple channels based on rules

Tags: communication

Does anyone know of an alerting system that has at least the following features

1. Receive alert via email or API
2. Able to send alert to various channels such as email, SMS, phone, instant message (such as Telegram, Whatsapp etc.)
3. Able to add user and put them in groups
4. Send out alert to different groups of users based on the levels or tags
5. Able to configure rules based on levels or tags in email/API, for example,

   - low - use email, send to level 1 team
   - medium - use SMS, send to level 1 + manager
   - high - use phone, call level 1

If the above functions are available as part of a bigger package such as a monitor software, that's fine. However, it should be able to function just as an alerting system.

The system can be self-hosted or SAAS.

If self-hosted, it should be open source and runs on Linux.

If SAAS, the pricing should be itemise and not by tiers. By this I mean if I have 53 configurations and sent 17 alerts, I'm charged for that. I should not need to pay a 100 config, 50 alert package monthly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? What do you think of the posted answer? It is ok to answer your own question; in fact, we like that, if it will help others in future

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [PagerDuty](https://pagerduty.com) which is a SaaS based solution focused on alerting with a per user pricing model which sounds like what you may be looking for. It has all the features you mentioned plus a whole lot of integrations as well.

They also have an [API](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/) if you want to customize your escalation rules and for receiving events.